# Tracking In-App Purchases from Affiliates

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to figure out how to track in-app purchases from specific affiliates.
I am tracking in app purchases, but is there a way to track specify where they came from?
Or will this just be a 2 part process of tracking installs from an affiliate and then matching that up with a purchase?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks